# Getting exception with spring5 after migrating from spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-security

Recently we have migrated spring from 4.3.x to 5.3.28 version and getting below exception when we used hibernate code from the spring.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:360) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.unwrap(SessionImpl.java:3899) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.18.Final.jar:5.3.18.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(HibernateTransactionManager.java:720) ~[spring-orm-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:992) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:790) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.createExtendedObjectType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.axeda.platform.sdk.v1.services.extobject.ExtendedObjectServiceImpl.createExtendedObjectType(ExtendedObjectServiceImpl.java:65) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.createExtendedObjectType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.axeda.platform.sdk.v1.services.extobject.ExtendedObjectSDKTest.before(ExtendedObjectSDKTest.java:71) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367) ~[surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274) ~[surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) ~[surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161) ~[surefire-junit4-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121) ~[surefire-booter-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]**

**Note: hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session property is set to true and We have upgraded only spring dependency.
```

Could you please confirm in which spring version the issue is resolved?
or is it required to set `hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session` to `false` to resolve the error?

While seraching for the issue found https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel.

Comment: What did you migrate? Only upgraded the dependencies or also other dependencies like Hibernate? Did you also upgrade your configuration to match the newer versions?

Comment: We have migrated all the spring dependencies to 5.3.28 version. We have hibernate 5.3.28 dependency as well in codebase.

Comment: So you not just upgraded spring but more... I would set the property to false (or just remove it) to avoid agressive session closing. You would also need to use the proper hibernate integration classes (depending on if you are using the `HibernateSessionFactoryBean` or `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

Comment: ** Right now we have upgraded only spring dependency. ** hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session property is set to true was working properly before spring migration.

so just wanted to check why it not working as before.

Comment: I think it didn't work before and now it actually does.

Comment: We have releases where that property is set true with spring 4. However with spring 5 the same code is not working.

Note: Observed that hibernate version in spring 4 is hibernate3 whereas in spring 5 it is hibernate5.

Comment: Read my comment. My suggestion is that the property didn't do anything with your previous configuration (even if it was there) and now it does work leading to eagerly closing the session, which will lead to issues if you lazy load collections which you will need. Hence the suggestion to remove it. Why did you add that property in the first place? The session will be closed automatically when the transaction ends anyway. Please update your question with the before/after configuration and dependencies (You didn't only upgrade spring) and add the **full stacktrace** instead of a snippet.

Comment: I have added the complete stack trace in the question.
Just for the clarification, we have upgraded only spring dependency nothing else.

Comment: You stated you upgraded from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5 as well, so that isn't just a Spring upgrade.

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace the `true` value (or the presence of that property) influences/impacts proper session management with Spring.

Comment: **Note: Observed that hibernate version in spring 4 is hibernate3 whereas in spring 5 it is hibernate5.**

If you are referring above line, my intension was out of the box spring code has hibernate classes as well refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/5.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5

where as in spring 4 :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/4.3.x/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3

so I was saying in spring 5 it uses hibernate 5

Comment: No it doesn't have Hibernate classes, it has hibernate support classes. It doesn't ship with Hibernate. That is a separate dependency which you need to add. But we are getting into technicalities here,  ditch the property and I suspect it will work as it will not  agressivly release the session anymore. I even would argue that it is a bug (of sorts in Hibernate) looking at the stacktrace, as with the `unwrap` call it checks if the `Session` is still open, which looks strange to me.

Comment: You are correct there is bug from hibernate please refer: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

post that no updates on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove the property as Spring will automatically close the session at the end of the transaction.

Looking at the stacktrace I would think this is a bug/feature in Hibernate. When doing an `unwrap` on the `EntityManager`/`Session` it does an eager check to see if it is closed. If closed it will throw an error instead of unwrapping to the requested object. Apparently there is already a [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11311?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) for this but that was closed due to inactivity.

That all being said, removing the property would make it work as Spring will automatically close the `Session` for you already. It might be that the `Session` is open slightly longer then it is now but I suspect that wouldn't lead to issues.